# How to Make a native REST API call?

Tags: sql-server, rest, t-sql

I would be glad to use something like Rethink database r.http command for accessing external APIs directly from the database.
It's syntax is very intuitive:

```
r.http('https://api.github.com/users/coffeemug', {
       auth: {
           user: GITHUB_TOKEN,
           pass: 'x-oauth-basic'
       }
})
```

Now:

- sp_OACreate/sp_OAMethod/sp_OADestroy approach seems to be be old-fashion/buggy/underperforming
- CLR stored procedures require to enable .NET integration and I want to avoid that

Does it exist any other valid solution? I heard about R-services but I didn't find any sample code to test.